# Error handling Azure Powershell - specific errors and responses

Tags: azure, powershell

Trying to get something set up in powershell that will eventually go into Azure automation.  Specifically, trying to add a new DNS record, using the following command:

```
$Hostname = "testhostname"
$Zone = "subdomain.domain.com"
$IP = "1.2.3.4"
$RG = "testresourcegroup"

New-AzureRMDNSRecordSet -Name "$Hostname" -RecordType A -ZoneName $Zone -ResourceGroupName $RG -ttl 3600 -DnsRecords (New-AzureRMDNSRecordConfig -IPv4address "$IP") -ErrorAction Stop
```

The command will return one of the following:

1) If the record already exists:

```
New-AzureRMDNSRecordSet : The Record set testhostname exists already and hence cannot be created again.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRMDNSRecordSet -Name "$Hostname" -RecordType A -ZoneName $Zo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet], CloudException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Dns.NewAzureDnsRecordSet
```

2)  If the IP is invalid:

```
New-AzureRMDNSRecordSet : The provided ip address '3333.4.21.11' is not valid.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRMDNSRecordSet -Name "$Hostname" -RecordType A -ZoneName $Zo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet], CloudException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Dns.NewAzureDnsRecordSet
```

3) It's successful:

```
Id                : /subscriptions/(subscriptionID)/resourceGroups/testresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/dnszones/subdomain.domain.com/A/testhostname
Name              : testhostname
ZoneName          : subdomain.domain.com
ResourceGroupName : testresourcegroup
Ttl               : 3600
Etag              : (removed)
RecordType        : A
TargetResourceId  :
Records           : {1.2.3.4}
Metadata          :
ProvisioningState : Succeeded
```

I'm trying to get errors, using the "try" "catch" but have not been successful.  Here's what I've tried:

```
try {
    New-AzureRMDNSRecordSet -Name "$Hostname" -RecordType A -ZoneName $Zone -ResourceGroupName $RG -ttl 3600 -DnsRecords (New-AzureRMDNSRecordConfig -IPv4address "$IP") -ErrorAction Stop #-ErrorVariable badIP -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-null
}
catch {
    Write-Host "There was an error"
}
```

I'd like to get it where based on the error RESPONSE, I can print a specific output.
Example, the first error: "The record set $Hostname exists already and hence cannot be created again".  I'd like to be able to take that and instead, just output to the user: "Duplicate hostname; please try another".

I'm struggling with how to put the specific errors in the 'catch'

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue in your powershell code. For `string`, you should use `.Contains()` instead of `-contains`.

I did not have your environment, so I just write a similar code for the error handling:

```
try
{
Copy-Item -Path d:\t2.txt -Destination d:\333\ -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{

$message = $_.Exception.message

if($message.Contains("Cannot find path"))
{
Write-Output "the source path is not correct"
}

if($message.Contains("The filename, directory name"))
{
Write-Output "the destination path is not correct"
}

}
```

And the test result is as below:
[image]

So for your case, the scripts should like below:

```
try 
{ 
New-AzureRMDNSRecordSet -Name "$Hostname" -RecordType A -ZoneName $Zone -ResourceGroupName $RG -ttl 3600 -DnsRecords (New-AzureRMDNSRecordConfig -IPv4address "$IP") -ErrorAction Stop  
} 

catch 
{ 

if ($_.Exception.Message.Contains("The provided IP address $IP is invalid"))
{ Write-Output "The IP is invalid" } 

if ($_.Exception.Message.Contains("exists already and hence"))
{ Write-Output "The hostname is duplicated; please pick another" } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the syntax

```
try {
}
catch [YourExceptionType.. e.g. Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException]
{
}
```

or use

```
$_.Exception
```

inside the catch block.

You can even have multiple catch blocks. 
The exact syntax is described in the following about_page:

```
get-help about_try_catch_finally -ShowWindow
```

Comment: But they are the same 'exception type' if i'm understanding correctly.  for instance, whether it's a duplicate hostname or an invalid IP, the exception type appears to be the same?

Comment: Then you can query the ```$_.Exception.Message``` inside the catch block... To get the details for the last error you might also query ```$Error[0]``` or ```$Error[0].GetType()```

Comment: So would that look like this?

try {
New-AzureRMDNSRecordSet -Name "$Hostname" -RecordType A -ZoneName $Zone -ResourceGroupName $RG -ttl 3600 -DnsRecords (New-AzureRMDNSRecordConfig -IPv4address "$IP") -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch [$_.Exception.Message contains "The provided IP address $IP is invalid"
{
Write-Output "The IP is invalid"
}
catch $_.Exception.Message contains "exists already and hence "
{
Write-Output "The hostname is duplicated; please pick another"
}


Would that be right?

Comment: catch {
 if ($_.Exception.Message -contains "The provided IP address $IP is invalid") { Write-Output "The IP is invalid" } 
 if ($_.Exception.Message -contains "exists already and hence ") { Write-Output "The hostname is duplicated; please pick another" }
}

Comment: You may want to check for properties other than the message that may help you. If you do `$_.Exception | Get-Member` you can get a full list. There may be potentially a `Body` property with useful information, if this is indeed the code for that exception: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/psSdkJson6/src/SdkCommon/ClientRuntime.Azure/ClientRuntime.Azure/CloudException.cs

Comment: Tried this, and got no output at all:

try
{
 New-AzureRMDNSRecordSet -Name "$Hostname" -RecordType A -ZoneName $Zone -ResourceGroupName $RG -ttl 3600 -DnsRecords (New-AzureRMDNSRecordConfig -IPv4address "$IP") -ErrorAction Stop #-ErrorVariable badIP -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-null
}
catch 
{ 
if 
($_.Exception.Message -contains "The provided IP address $IP is invalid") 
{ Write-Output "The IP is invalid" } 
if 
($_.Exception.Message -contains "exists already and hence ") 
{ Write-Output "The hostname is duplicated; please pick another" } 
}

Comment: This time I got just the red error message; not the write output

Comment: This is what I have:

try
{
 New-AzureRMDNSRecordSet -Name "$Hostname" -RecordType A -ZoneName $Zone -ResourceGroupName $RG -ttl 3600 -DnsRecords (New-AzureRMDNSRecordConfig -IPv4address "$IP") #-ErrorAction Stop #-ErrorVariable badIP -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-null
}
catch 
{ 
if 
($_.Exception.Message -contains "The provided IP address $IP is invalid") 
{ Write-Output "The IP is invalid" } 
if 
($_.Exception.Message -contains "exists already and hence ") 
{ Write-Output "The hostname is duplicated; please pick another" } 
}